# Does "tensoring" with a fixed field preserve Galois extensions of finite fields?

Tags: galois-theory, finite-fields, fields, tensor-products

Let $K$ be a (possibly infinite) field of characteristic $p$, and $L$ be a finite field extension of $\mathbb{F}_p$, so that $L$ is finite and $L/\mathbb{F}_p$ is Galois. Suppose $K \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} L$ is a field, can we conclude that $(K \otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p} L) / K$ is Galois? If not, what are some sufficient conditions for this conclusion to hold?

Comment: The tensor product of two fields will not in general be a field.

Comment: Yes you are right. Let me make an edit.

Comment: Yes. The action of the Galois group $G$ on $L$ extends to an action on $K\otimes _{\mathbb{F}_p}L$, and since the functor $K\otimes _{\mathbb{F}_p}-$ is exact, the $G$-invariant subfield is  $K\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p}\mathbb{F}_p=K$. Thus  $(K\otimes_{\mathbb{F}_p}L)/K$ is Galois with group $G$.

Comment: Your argument seems to not require any assumption of finiteness of the fields or of the extension. Is that correct?